# How to disable/change animation between views in ion-nav-view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, css-animations

I started an Ionic tabs project. With this project comes the default animation between views (which is from left to right when entering, and from right to left when going back). I would like to retain control on this - by specifying two type of view animations:

- from bottom to up
- no animation

So far I tried to disable the animation as follows, as was suggested on this [Ionic Forum Topic](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-nav-view-animations/2605) but it did not change anything:

```
<ion-nav-view animation="no-animation"></ion-nav-view>
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE').config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
});
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider#views.transition

Answer (score 4):

Another way.

The transition type which the nav view transition should use when it animates.
Current, options are ios, android, and none.

Home

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/navTransition/